# Can't bloke specific website editing hosts file in Mac

Tags: macos, hosts

I've tried to bloke some website (here www.lichess.org) through the HOSTS file in Mac, which work perfectly for any other websites.

I wrote in the folder :

```
127.0.0.1       https://www.lichess.org
```

(and tried some other combinations, with http:// instead of https:// and so on)

I did not forge to clear the DNS cache with the command

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Any idea why it's not working ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the protocol, so your entry would be:

```
127.0.0.1       www.lichess.org
```